# Pyrogram: how to retrive a selected info using get_me()

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

i need to create a command in my userbot that if the user use it his username will be (normal username) + ONLINE. Im trying to use get_me() for getting the username but i get all the infos. I need only username... How i can do this?

Comment: could you add some more information around the library you're using and include any code you currently have

Answer (score 0):

`get_me()` should return a dictionary like this:

```
{'first_name': 'Your Bot', 'username': 'YourBot', 'id': 123456789}
```

You can access the values of a dictionary with the corresponding key.
If you want the username, it would look like this:

```
get_me()['username']
```